# php function call inside string variable

Tags: php, string, variables

I'm working with wordpress, and have stoped with a problem, I can't figure out how to deal with quotes and php code inside a string.

working code:

```
$wrap .= '<li class="qx-nav-logo">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/theme/logo-nav.svg" />
                </a>
            </li>';
```

what I want to apply, is the href attribute value inside 'a' tag

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>
```

I tried with double quotes and signle insides, and other way, but I does not work.

could You write me, how does it have to be done?

Comment: why don't you just cut your string into several different pieces - so the URL-part is one by itself that you actually can give to esc_url? also: that's *not* PHP inside a string. that's HTML inside a string. which, for PHP, is just text without any meaning whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the strings in such manner:

```
$wrap .= '<li class="qx-nav-logo">
                <a href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'">
                    <img src="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/theme/logo-nav.svg" />
                </a>
            </li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

As @FranzGleichmann commented, It can be done differently and this is probably the best way, just to save our url to some variable first and than put it in place.

```
  $homeurl = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );

  $wrap .= "<li class='qx-nav-logo'>
                <a href='{$homeurl}'>
                    <img src='http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/theme/logo-nav.svg' />
                </a>
            </li>";
```